# Google Plus api access

Tags: google-api

I have a WEB APP running on Google APP Engine.

I want the APP to ask users to give permission to let the WEB APP post to to their Google Plus page.

I have this working for Facebook and Twitter - I get the access KEy and store it against their user.

I have read on the Web that Google Plus API does NOT allow updates.
Is this true or can I achieve what I am trying to do.

I have it so the user logs on each time at present - a bit poor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible, an easy way to get you started is to use the sample project generator by google:

https://developers.google.com/qs/?api=plus&language=python&samples=python_appengine_skeleton

on that link, I've already selected python on app engine with google+ API, you can change it to Java if that is your language of choice.

After the user authorized the app, he will only have to be logged in with her google account to access your application, no need for anything else.